low quality answers and posts - instawallet software
I assure you with over 20 years experience with microsoft products and the internet having my forst computer in 1998 I know what im talking about when it come to ithe internet and related.  I have a 3.7 gpa from a nice high school near a nasa compaund and 20.5 university honors credits from UALr in Little Rock, Ar.  I fail to see what is low quality about my questions and posts related to the instawallet software wallet i used on March 1, 2011.  To my knowledge the information i gave is true and correct aside from fraudulent claims stating otherwise i see no reason to grade my post as low quality.  I challeng the moderator to have a more open view of the early bitcoin era and accept my information as near fact or fact as stated.  please treat me with respect as i do have over 20 years experience with the internet and bough  my forst bitcoin on march 1, 2011.  Please allow me to receive answers and offer any revision suggestions to fit in your webstites guidelines.

It seems like you may be misunderstanding how to use bitcoin.stackexchange.com
You've added quite a few answers where you're asking for help.
You should add a new, clearly defined question using the ask a question button.
Please take the tour and take a little time to read through the help center for guidance on how to best use the site.
